# Type error yet the two variables are both integers

Tags: python

Here is the code:

This is where `startTime` and `endTime` are declared. I'm not sure if I should do IntVar or StringVar because they did not work before.

```
startTime = str
endTime = str

def start1():
    Canvas1 = Canvas(ReactionTest,width = 500,height = 450)
    Canvas1.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=3,pady=10)
    image_1 = PhotoImage(file="photo_1.gif")
    Canvas1.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW, image=image_1)
    Canvas1.image_1=image_1
    startTime = time.strftime('%S')
def end1():
    endTime = time.strftime('%S')
    calctimeTaken = int(endTime) - int(startTime)
    timeTaken = str(calctimetaken)
```

Traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\brent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\brent\OneDrive\Desktop\Computer Science\Program\WonderWalls Program.py", line 810, in end1
    calctimeTaken = int(endTime) - int(startTime)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'type'
```

Comment: It seems that startTime is a type, when it should be a string, a bytes-like object or a number for it to work, as says the Traceback

Comment: how would i fix that, Nenri?

Comment: May you show where your `startTime` is declared?

Comment: try removing `int` from both of them and check which value is stored in the `calctimetaken`

Comment: The value that `startTime` has inside `start1` may not necessarily match what value it has in `end1`, because `startTime` is a local variable. I suspect you also have a global `startTime`, or else end1 would crash with a NameError. Please provide a [mcve] that shows how all of your values are initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your variable is not global and you only declare the varible inside a function.
Give a try with the follow code:

```
startTime = 0
def start1():
    global startTime
    Canvas1 = Canvas(ReactionTest,width = 500,height = 450)
    Canvas1.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=3,pady=10)
    image_1 = PhotoImage(file="photo_1.gif")
    Canvas1.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW, image=image_1)
    Canvas1.image_1=image_1
    startTime = time.strftime('%S')
def end1():
    global startTime
    endTime = time.strftime('%S')
    calctimeTaken = int(endTime) - int(startTime)
    timeTaken = str(calctimetaken)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem that you have two individual functions? Variables by default are not scoped out of a function. You can remedy this by declaring them outside of the function and using "global startTime" to declare them in a function, or by declaring them outside and then passing them into a function as parameters.

I suspect you're subtracting empty from endTime or something here